# overlapping css when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I am making my first webpage and am having trouble positioning elements. They keep overlapping each other when I resize the browser. The title is positioned absolute, but this means it overlaps the image at the top. I cant get it into position by any other means. Can anyone help?

here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Guitar Lessons</title>
      <link href="./bio.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Images\guitar_banner.jpg" alt="Dunc's guitar lessons in Isleworth"/>
     <div class="cont">
      <div class="top-left">Dunc's<br/> Guitar<br/> Lessons</div>
        </div>
       <nav class="navigation">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Guitar lessons\bio.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p class="first">About Me</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Guitar lessons\my music.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p class="second">My Music</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Guitar lessons\FAQ.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p class="third">FAQ</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Guitar lessons\prices.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p class="fourth">Prices</p></a></li>
          <li><a href="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Guitar lessons\contact.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p class="fifth">Contact</p></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>     
  <h2 id="bio">My Bio</h2>
  <p class="bio">Hello! I am Duncan – famous for imparting my guitar knowledge on the residents of Isleworth. I have been playing the guitar for over ten years and can navigate<br/> the fretboard confidently. I am completely self-taught, and it’s been a real learning curve which I am keen to pass on to others wishing to learn the guitar. Through<br/> my learning experience, I realise the value of having human interaction and feedback whilst learning. I am a very patience teacher, which makes me<br/> suitable for teaching beginners.<br/><br/>
  My musical influences are based heavily on the blues, and my favourite guitarists include Peter Green, Muddy Waters, B.B. King, Jimmy Page, Eric Clapton,<br/> Wilko Johnson and Jimmy Hendrix. I have recently started to write my own music, with the aim one day of recording properly and creating a short album.   
 </p>


   <h2 id="lessons">Lesson Content</h2>
     <p class="content">I specialise in taking complete beginners through the different aspects of playing the guitar and I aim to have you confident and skilled enough to play a<br/> short piece of music (something other than a nursery rhyme!) within just three lessons. Aspects of playing my lessons cover include:</p>
       <ul class="lessons">
         <li>Basic open chord shapes</li>
         <li>Strumming patterns and rhythm</li>
         <li>Learning notes on the fret board</li>
         <li>Lead techniques and single note lines</li>
         <li>Advice on gear and the best guitars to buy</li>
       </ul>
     <p class="content">Practice makes perfect, and you are given homework between each lesson to play on your guitar.</p><br/><br/>

   <div class="guitar"> 
     <img src="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Images\guitar.jpg" />
       </div>

       <br/>
      <p class="copyright">Copyright Duncan Hammett 2018</p><br/>
</body>
```

here is the css:

```
nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 50px;
    }

.first {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
border: 2px solid maroon;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: maroon;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
font-size: 28px;

  }

 .first:hover {
color: teal;
 }

  .second {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
border: 2px solid maroon;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: maroon;
color: white;
font-size: 28px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
 }

.second:hover {
color: teal;
 }

  .third {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
border: 2px solid maroon;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: maroon;
color: white;
font-size: 28px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

 .third:hover {
color: teal;
 }

  .fourth {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
border: 2px solid maroon;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: maroon;
color: white;
font-size: 28px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.fourth:hover {
color: teal;
}

.fourth {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
border: 2px solid maroon;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: maroon;
color: white;
font-size: 28px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.fifth {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
border: 2px solid maroon;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: maroon;
color: white;
font-size: 28px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}


.fifth:hover {
color: teal;
}

.header img {
width: 1440px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
left: 240px; 
min-width: 1440px;
max-width: 1440px;
min-height: 400px;
max-height: 400px;  
 }

.cont {
position: relative;
}

.top-left {
position: absolute;
top: 11px;
left: 12px;
color: teal;
font-size: 124px;
}

body {
font-family: Helvetica;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}

.guitar img {
width: 1100px;
height: 600px;
position: static;
min-width: 1100px;
max-width: 1100px;
min-height: 600px;
max-height: 600px; 
}

.bio {
line-height: 1.6;
color: teal;
}

.content {
line-height: 1.6;
color: teal;
}

.lessons {
line-height: 1.6;
list-style-position: inside;
color: teal; 
 }

 .copyright {
    color: teal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples of CSS Layouts you could learn from. CSS Tricks has a [Grid Start Layouts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-grid-starter-layouts/) that provides numerous examples and code samples to learn from.

Comment: You might want to look into something like Bootstrap (if you'd rather not reinvent the wheel). https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Sorry, this hasn't answered my question. Please could someone help me. The text below wont stay put: